# Методы класса для дочерних классов Ruby

Tags: ruby

Решая задачу, наткнулся на такой код
Условие задачи:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5200165c39ae4c612200027b/

```
class Mother
  def self.phone_kids
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) {|klass| klass.phone if klass < Mother}
  end
end
Mother.phone_kids
class Foo < Mother
end

class Bar < Mother
end
```

он выводится без ошибок, что меня немного смущает, ведь метод phone нигде не определен, не могли бы помочь разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выполнять код именно в такой последовательности, как в вашем вопросе, то отсутствие ошибок вполне понятно.

Вы вызываете `Mother.phone_kids` до того, как определили `Foo` и `Bar`, значит условие `if klass < Mother` не выполняется ни для одного класса, значит `klass.phone` не вызывается.

Если же классы определить до вызова `Mother.phone_kids`, то получаем ожидаемую `undefined method 'phone' for Foo:Class`.

Comment: Осознал, что вопрос глупый, но все равно спасибо